# Drupal Views: Programmatically alter a View and execute to array

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, default

Essentially I have a View called '**promo**' that's built on a Nodequeue. It is being restricted to 1 row, and order by Global:Random

The view itself is being used for a block on the site.

Additionally, the view same view is being for a node reference field '**field_promo**'.

What I would like to do is to obtain the 2 most recent rows from the **promo** view, and use these as the default values for **field_promo**.

What this requires is that I:

- load the view
- remove the **global:random** sort
- add a **created** sort
- change pager to display 2 rows instead of 1
- execute the view

...

Since writing all this and making sure I'm not an idiot, I've gathered together the solution which I may as well post below since it took me so long to find it! (will post solution after 8 hours, I'll give points if you crack the answer before I get to post :P)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
$view = views_get_view('promo_feature');
$view->init_display();
$view->preview=TRUE;
$view->is_cacheable = FALSE;
$view->display_handler->set_option('items_per_page',2);
$view->set_item('default', 'sort', 'random', NULL);
$view->add_item('default', 'sort', 'node', 'created',array('order' => 'DESC'));
$view->pre_execute();
$output = $view->display_handler->preview();
$view->post_execute();

$return=array();
foreach($view->result as $row){
  $return[]=array('nid' => $row->nid);
}

return($return);
```

$view->set_item($display,$type,$id,NULL) removes that item from the view

I suspect there's a more refined version of this code, however it took me so long to get there I'm afraid to touch it in case I destroy it :)